# VBA Use Printer via unique identifier

Tags: ms-access, printing, vba

I am programming an Access form which needs to print. Since I am not developing the form on the same computer as the computer it will be used on, I can't be sure the printers name will be the same and if it will be the standard printer. My first attempt was to list all printers using `Application.Printers`.

The problem is that I can't find a pattern in the devices name or anything to identify the right printer. Is there any smart attempt on this, using for example the MAC adress or the IP of the printer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-networked printers don't have unique identifiers. The combination printer name + computer name should be unique, though.

For networked printers, you can try using the `.Port` property to identify a certain printer. However, this property is configurable, and is a string.

If you want to get the IP address of a certain printer, you will have to use the `EnumPorts` function ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162687(v=vs.85).aspx)) to get the available ports and their associated IP addresses. Since that's a C++ function, that's not very easy. Then, using the `.Port` property, you can identify which printer is using that port.